# modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found in directory /lib/modules/

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I had an issue recently after successfully installing and testing Tensorflow compiled with GPU support.

After rebooting the machine, I got the following error Message when I tried to run a Tensorflow program:

```
...
('Extracting', 'MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')  
modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:491] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:140] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (caffe-desktop): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:92] No GPU devices available on machine.
(0, 114710.45)
(1, 95368.891)
...
(98, 56776.922)
(99, 57289.672)
```

[Screencapture of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgQo3.png)

Code: https://github.com/llSourcell/autoencoder_demo

Question: Why would restarting a Ubuntu 16.04 machine break Tensorflow?

Answer (score 6):

I actually solved my own problem and wanted to share the solution which worked for me.

The magic Google search was:
"modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia-uvm not found in directory /lib/modules/"

Which led me to the following answer on askubuntu:
https://askubuntu.com/a/496146

That answer's author, *Sneetsher*, did a really good job of explaining so if the link doesn't 404 I would start there.

**Cliff Notes**

Diagnosis: I suspected that Ubuntu may have installed a kernel update when I rebooted.

Solution: Reinstalling the NVIDIA driver fixed the error.

Problem: NVIDIA drivers cannot be installed with X server running

**Two different ways to fix the NVIDIA Driver**

**1) Keyboard and Monitor:**

*Paraphrasing the askubuntu answer:*

> 1) Switch to text-only console (Ctrl+Alt+F1 or any to F6).
>
> 2) Build driver modules for the current kernel (which just installed) `sudo ./<DRIVER>.run -K`

credit "Sneetsher" : https://askubuntu.com/a/496146

*I don't have a keyboard or monitor attached to this PC so here's the "headless" approach I actually used:*

**2) Over SSH:**

Following this guide to reboot to console:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/

```
$ sudo cp -n /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.orig
$ sudo nano /etc/default/grub
$ sudo update-grub
```

edit the grub file according to above link(3 changes):

> 1. Comment the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash”, by adding # at the beginning, which will disable the Ubuntu purple screen.
> 2. Change GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”text”, this makes Ubuntu boot directly into Text Mode.
> 3. Uncomment this line #GRUB_TERMINAL=console, by removing the # at the beginning, this makes Grub Menu into real black & white Text Mode (without background image)
> 4. UPDATE: (If running Ubuntu 16.04 If 
>      $ sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
> 5. Reboot into console

```
$ sudo shutdown -r now
$ sudo service lightdm stop
$ sudo ./<DRIVER>.run
```

follow the NVIDIA driver installer

```
$ sudo mv /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.textonly 
$ sudo mv /etc/default/grub.orig /etc/default/grub 
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

**Results** *(What things look like now the GPU was successfully detected)*

```
...
('Extracting', 'MNIST_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:118] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.342
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.94GiB
Free memory: 3.88GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:138] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:148] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:868] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
(0, 113040.92)
(1, 94895.867)
...
```

[Screencapture of the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bl3IT.png)

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the exact same problem . I followed your instructions, but I didn't get the line sudo ./<DRIVER>.run , should I run it exactly the same  or <DRIVER> should be replaced with something or should I first download some driver file and then run it .... ?

Comment: <DRIVER>.run is the filename of the NVIDIA Driver you downloaded from the NVIDIA site. In my case: this filename was "NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run" which can be downloaded from here: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/104284/en-us This assumes you have a 64 bit x86 CPU, and that you don't need a more recent driver version. If 367.27 is no longer current for your purpose, you may have to substitute a more recent driver version.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to "Problem: NVIDIA drivers cannot be installed with X server running:

1. Access ubuntu from another computer using SSH
2. Remove the screen (display device) of Ubuntu computer
3. Reboot computer using sudo reboot, then access it again